# How do I give automation commands/ instructions after logging into PuTTy

Tags: putty

I searched and didnt find much help.

Using Plink.exe

After logging in (which I can launch from command line), pass as a string argument for my `system()` command,

`plink user@10.140.144.80 -pw password`

I need to pass just one command to start an iperf server

`iperf -s -i 1 -w 2m -p 5115 -u -l 1400`

How do I do that? plink allows me to give some batch files as a command line argument with one of the options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. plink.exe allows you to pass a batch file as as an argument which can contain all the instructions/commands you wish to give in it.

It was pretty straight forward and simple.